# how to animate the a particular label from bottom to top in swift

Tags: swift, animation

I want to animate label from bottom to top.

I am using this code

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], 
animations: {
    quoteLbl.center.y -= self.view.bounds.height - 100
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```

but this code  animate the whole view and I want to animate a particular label of UIViewController

Comment: This is the second question i see in a short time about animating stuff. And people have started to use frames and try to move the y and x coordinates of a frame. What you should do is to use anchorpoints to bind items to other items and then change the anchor points you want to affect.

Comment: @poornima-mishra 2 points 1. you need not write `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` you are already changing `center.y` in an animation block 2. It works, it does not move the view it simply moves the label, you can probably edit the question with bit more context and add either a screenshot or gif of whats happening to help us get better idea